# How best to combine documents for XSLT processing?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have a bunch of reports which are individually edited and transformed (xml -> xsl-fo) to create pdf files.  In addition I would like to combine all the reports into a book to be created using a single transformation.  I thought I could use the **document()** function for this:

(Individual reports look like this):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE blue_book SYSTEM "../DTD/blue_book.dtd">
<blue_book>

  ~~stuff~~

</blue_book>
```

I create a placeholder file called, say, reports.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<reports>
  <report filename="title.xml"/>
  <report filename="preface.xml"/>
  <report filename="report1.xml"/>
  <report filename="report2.xml"/>
  <report filename="report3.xml"/>
  <report filename="report4.xml"/>
</reports>
```

and then use something like this in my stylesheet to crank through them:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/reports/report">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@filename)/blue_book"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This sort of works, but all the code I've created to start page-numbering and autogenerate id's based on location in the document for linking purposes falls apart.  For example, I want page numbering to start on the 3rd report.  If I just cat all the xml files together into a single file, the following works fine.

```
<xsl:template match="blue_book">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::blue_book) &lt; 2">
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="front-matter">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::blue_book) = 2">
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="report">
        <xsl:attribute name="initial-page-number">1</xsl:attribute>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="first-xsl-region-before">
            <xsl:if test="lead_para">
              <fo:block font-variant="small-caps" text-align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="lead_para"/></fo:block>
            </xsl:if>
          <fo:block>&#x00A0;</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
(etc. -- lots of xsl-fo)
```

but when loading files using the **document()** function, it appears that the preceding-sibling count is always 0; i.e. it's only looking at that particular report and not considering the ones loaded previously.

This makes sense, but doesn't solve my problem.  Is there a standard way to do this?  In particular, I'd like to process all the reports *as if they were in the same XML document*  but without having to actually physically concatenate them together.*

*If anyone is wondering why, it's because the editors want to maintain and edit the reports individually but still be able to run something through AH Formatter which gives them the complete book.  Concatenation of files is outside their skill set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you really need to, you can build a composite document:

```
<xsl:variable name="composite">
 <composite>
   <xsl:for-each select="/reports/report">
     <xsl:copy-of select="document(@filename)/blue_book"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </composite>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, you'll need to use exslt:node-set($composite) to do further processing on this variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I am stuck using XSLT 1.0 (it would be too complicated to not default to MSXML on Windows 7 for this project).  However, I guess I would really only need to modify the root template to get this to work, since this would generate a node set that would look "normal" to the other templates in the stylesheet.  I'm finding that the not being able to save and work with temporary trees in XSLT 1.0 is a major handicap and will likely resort to using exslt by default in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use entities? Simply change the way you are creating the placeholder file. You asked:

"In particular, I'd like to process all the reports as if they were in the same XML document but without having to actually physically concatenate them together."

Yes, use entities. If I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE reports [
<!ENTITY title SYSTEM "title.xml">
<!ENTITY document1 SYSTEM "document1.xml">
]>
<reports>
    &title;
    &document1;
</reports>
```

And I have title.xml as this:

```
<blue_book>
    <title>I am the title of title</title>
</blue_book>
```

And document1.xml as this:

```
<blue_book>
    <title>I am the title of document 1</title>
</blue_book>
```

The xpath //reports/blue_book/title yields:

System ID: F:\RenderX\Demonstrations\Tricks\Image\title.xml
Description: I am the title of title
XPath location: /reports[1]/blue_book[1]/title[1]
Start location: 2:5
End location: 2:43

System ID: F:\RenderX\Demonstrations\Tricks\Image\document1.xml
Description: I am the title of document 1
XPath location: /reports[1]/blue_book[2]/title[1]
Start location: 2:5
End location: 2:48

And count(//reports/blue_book) returns "2" so I have not tested, but it seems to me everything you have done would work without document()

Comment: [1 of 2] I used entities before, but that was when we were still compiling the document on a linux system using a script.  Your `title.xml` and `document1.xml` are not valid XML files, as the XML header is missing.  If I leave the headers in the files, entities don't work; at least not using Xalan (to test fo creation) or Antenna House.  And removing these headers prior to formatting for 40+ chapters is not something the editor (using a Windows 7 machine) can do easily.

Comment: [2 of 2] Interestingly enough, we were using RenderX previously and didn't run into this problem.  I actually didn't bother to check to see if this works with RenderX, as we're using way too many axf: custom features to switch renderers.  OK, just checked, and xep can't handle the XML headers, either.

Comment: If you have a system where you cannot remove the declaration then you can use XInclude like docbook. See http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Xinclude.html. Note, its not invalid to not have a declaration. It is not the renderer RenderX or AH, it is xslt where you need this step.

Comment: And just to be clear, you XML above state version 1.0 and if you read the standard, it would say that the declaration *should* be used (not must be used) and therefore removing the declaration should mean nothing. In fact, you should only need to remove it once and nothing *should* put it back in. If you can;t do that, then XInclude can be used with either Xalan or Saxon to include only the document element as discussed in the link in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  The editors use XMetal to edit the XML documents, and Xmetal will complain if it can't find an XML header. It uses the DTD to decide if the document is valid, which is an extremely important feature with regard to preventing users from screwing up XML documents.

Comment: It would not work if you have <!DOCTYPE ...> directives on the individual XMLs anyway, regardless of the XML PI. You could use XInclude in processing and setup your solution with Xalan to include those JARs as written in the Docbook guides. This is how I would do it.  Or you could also do something like @Michael Kay says below but just creates a interim concatenated XML file via XSLand not use exslt. Or use his solution to create an XML in memory as a variable and use exslt to process that. All are solutions to the problem as it is not "unsolvable".

Comment: It looks like XInclude is not going to help me:  "An XML external entity cannot be a full-blown independent XML document—neither standalone XML declaration nor Doctype declaration is allowed. That effectively means an XML external entity itself cannot include other external entities." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx    I agree the problem is solvable; even on MS Windows I can install cygwin or powershell and write a script which strips the headers and cats the documents together.

Comment: I think you may be reading that wrong, that is a bullet from the list of why XInclude does work and why entities do not work.